# React Native - FlatList not scrolling on Andoird Emulator but does on iOS Emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

EDIT: I figured it out. Turns out the way android is set up, scrolling is not enabled *until* contents overflow. iOS lets you scroll no matter the status of the contents. If you tried everything else and it's not working for you, try debugging with a long list of data to make sure it overflows.

I am trying to get FlatList to be able to scroll through a list and it's not working on the android emulator. ScrollView also does not work.

I've been breaking it down into simpler and simpler components to see where the issue is but none of it has worked. And I tried the advice from every thread on this issue I could find. Almmost all of them just say "Set your View to flex: 1" but even if I do that it doesn't work. The threads that don't say that that had different advice also doesn't have an affect. Wrapping FlatList in another View, adding styling to the FlatList, importing FlatList from gesture handler instead of react-native, setting nestedScrollEnabled={true}, various additional flex properties and styling, none of it works. If anyone has had the same problem I would love some help. I'm using expo so if there are files specific to android I would have to edit I'm not sure they're available to me.

```
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'


export default function DebugScreen(){
    const test: Array<object> = [
        {
            key: 1,
            text: 'test item 1'
        },
        {
            key: 2,
            text: 'test item 2'
        },
        {
            key: 3,
            text: 'test item 3'
        }
    ]
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, height: 100, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <FlatList
                
                data={test}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Text>{item.text}</Text>
                        )}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```